# Doesn't the videophone play in the Safari browser?

Tags: html, css, safari

[image]
I've made a video phone for the site and it's displayed correctly on all browsers, except Safari. I tried to fix it, but nothing helps. What might be the problem?

```
<div class="main-video-bg" id="main-video-bg">
  <video preload="metadata" muted="muted" playsinline autoplay loop poster="./img/video/stalnoff.jpg" id="main-video-bg">
    <source src="./img/video/stalnoff.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="./img/video/stalnoff.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="./img/video/stalnoff.ogv" type="video/ogv">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Safari desktop, or Safari on iOS?

Comment: @ceejayoz Safari on phone. I'm testing the site through Browserstack. And instead of a video phone, it shows the Play button, although all the settings I've made are listed, and that should have helped.

Comment: Hmm. I thought your problem might be [the restrictions on `autoplay`](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/), but you appear to have ticked those boxes.

Comment: @ceejayoz I can drop out of the site itself, but after reading all the problems that Safari has with it, I have added all the possible features that StackOverflow has to offer.